# Expressionengine 2 and git (version control)

Tags: php, svn, git, expressionengine

I’m looking to move over to using git to make my EE development a lot easier and more manageable. I’m already aware of the guides posted on devotee and a few othersites but after scanning over them they seem a little old and seem to be specifically for ee 1.x, I was wondering if anyone had been successful with ee 2. I’ve only recently made the transition from svn to git, previously I found that using ee via svn was a ballache, so many confit conflicts, wrong urls, and all versions of the site were using the same database. I’m basically looking for the best or should I say the ideal way to setup both git and ee to work in harmony together. I’d like to also learn how to branch other sites I develop with ee from this too, if anyone has experience with this that’d be great!

Also if it’s any use I’m hosted by dreamhost, As far as I understand they support git, I’ve looked over their knowledge base on how best to set things up, would anyone reccomend their way of doing things? And has anyone had a successful experience whilst doing so?

I look forward to hearing your responses!

Thanks

Sent from my iPhone, whilst falling asleep so excuse the possible typos!a

Comment: Anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Gititon](http://gititon.masugadesign.com/)

My flow is as follows.

1. I've installed git on my local machine. (via macports)
2. Git Server: for me
   that's Beanstalk (http://www.beanstalkapp.com),

In the presentation from the above link,
    you'll see that Github (http://www.github.com) is in between
    the local git and Beanstalk. But for
    me, that's kinda an overhead,
    because I'm the only developer for
    the moment, maybe I'll add it later.

**Advantage**: with beanstalk you can deploy via (s)ftp to a staging or production server. You don't need to install git on your hosting solution.

Hope it helps!